# How to fix annoying Visual Studio text editor cursor misplacement bug

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio

Often, when I select and copy some lines in VB.NET or C# in Visual Studio text editor,
and then click and press Ctrl to copy them,
and then try to position the cursor where I want the copy of the lines to go,
in order to copy the lines to go before other lines, 
you must position the cursor at the exact 1st column at the target location,
BUT!!! if I position cursor just a little too far to the left, the cursor suddenly jumps up to 10 or so lines upward.

I've seen this problem from VS2017 back a version or two, and on many different Windows computers and the last few versions of Windows.
On come installations it never happens; on most others, it always happens.

It is a tedious annoyance.

Comment: Remove extensions until the bug goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.
After being annoyed by this for 3 years, on several different desktops and laptops at various client sites, it is fixed.

SOLUTION:
Visual Studio installer > click More > click Repair ... takes a while then needs to restart.
After restart, problem gone.

I'm presently using VS2017 Pro but problem has been common back to VS2015 and maybe earlier.

(The guy's suggestion up in the question comments I did not try, but it led me to consider good 'ol repair.)

Comment: Aug 2018:  Problem has been back, on both Win10 desktop and Win 10 laptop.

Comment: Yay!  This solution worked again, on both desktop and laptop.  Seems to be a Visual Studio bug.